# Unity build closing with permission problems

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, build, console

I'm making a game for mac on unity with my mac but when I play the build it immediately closes. It has worked before, but the only major change I have made since it was working is reinstalling and updating unity.

This is what my console printed when it closed:

[image]

I've looked up the errors but everything I've found relates to mac specific apps and I couldn't find anything that helped. Anyone know what the problem is? Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Some of the stuff I looked up points toward this being a permissions problem, so there might be a problem with folder access? I've been going through most of the folders and running chmod 755 in terminal but so far no luck.

Comment: A few notes: I have shared the project with some friends and they were also unable to have it start so it doesn't appear to be a problem with my computer. When I build the project Unity says the build was successful. I built the example project that comes with Unity and it worked fine.

Comment: Another note: I made a Windows version and shared it with some friends and that version does work.